# How to resize and crop an image into a square in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, crop, image-resizing

I wanted to crop my profile images into squares and reduce their size. So I googled "image resize matrix." None of the results matched my need, so I wrote my own code. It's in python/django. I decided most images of a head have more space on the bottom because of the neck and shoulders. So I cropped heights from the top, instead of from the middle. All of the widths are cropped to the middle. It uses 300 pixels as a maximum. I suppose this might help someone who has a similar task.

I need more points so I can vote on stuff. I use the site all day and get lots of answers, but I can't vote. Which makes me feel guilty.

```
from PIL import Image

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # User model fields, etc
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        width, height = img.size  # Get dimensions

        if width > 300 and height > 300:
            # keep ratio but shrink down
            img.thumbnail((width, height))
            width, height = img.size

            # check which one is smaller
            if height < width:
                # make square by cutting off equal amounts left and right
                left = (width - height) / 2
                right = (width + height) / 2
                top = 0
                bottom = height
                img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
                img.thumbnail((300, 300))
                img.save(self.image.path)

            elif width < height:
                # make square by cutting off bottom
                left = 0
                right = width
                top = 0
                bottom = width
                img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
                img.thumbnail((300, 300))
                img.save(self.image.path)
            else:
                # already square
                img.thumbnail((300, 300))
                img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width > 300 and height == 300:
            left = (width - 300) / 2
            right = (width + 300) / 2
            top = 0
            bottom = 300
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width > 300 and height < 300:
            left = (width - height) / 2
            right = (width + height) / 2
            top = 0
            bottom = height
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width < 300 and height > 300:
            # most potential for disaster
            left = 0
            right = width
            top = 0
            bottom = width
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width < 300 and height < 300:
            if height < width:
                left = (width - height) / 2
                right = (width + height) / 2
                top = 0
                bottom = height
                img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
                img.save(self.image.path)
            elif width < height:
                height = width
                left = 0
                right = width
                top = 0
                bottom = height
                img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
                img.save(self.image.path)
            else:
                img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width == 300 and height > 300:
            # potential for disaster
            left = 0
            right = 300
            top = 0
            bottom = 300
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width == 300 and height < 300:
            left = (width - height) / 2
            right = (width + height) / 2
            top = 0
            bottom = height
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width < 300 and height == 300:
            left = 0
            right = width
            top = 0
            bottom = width
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            img.save(self.image.path)

        elif width and height == 300:
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: I would suggest you to ask a proper question regarding your problem in details, then put the last part of your question (this code) as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your codes with us but your code is not well written, for example you repeated the same condition blocks 3 times which is unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

You repeated the same condition blocks 3 times which makes your code hard to read and maintain.

The code below is the exact same procedure you follow without that repeat I mentioned.

```
from PIL import Image

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # User model fields, etc
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        width, height = img.size  # Get dimensions

        if width > 300 and height > 300:
            # keep ratio but shrink down
            img.thumbnail((width, height))

        # check which one is smaller
        if height < width:
            # make square by cutting off equal amounts left and right
            left = (width - height) / 2
            right = (width + height) / 2
            top = 0
            bottom = height
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

        elif width < height:
            # make square by cutting off bottom
            left = 0
            right = width
            top = 0
            bottom = width
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

        if width > 300 and height > 300:
            img.thumbnail((300, 300))

        img.save(self.image.path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
from PIL import Image

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # User model fields, etc
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.user_profile_img.path)

        # When image height is greater than its width
        if img.height > img.width:
            # make square by cutting off equal amounts top and bottom
            left = 0
            right = img.width
            top = (img.height - img.width)/2
            bottom = (img.height + img.width)/2
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            # Resize the image to 300x300 resolution
            if img.height > 300 or img.width >300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.user_profile_img.path)

        # When image width is greater than its height
        elif img.width > img.height:
            # make square by cutting off equal amounts left and right
            left = (img.width - img.height)/2
            right = (img.width + img.height)/2
            top = 0
            bottom = img.height
            img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
            # Resize the image to 300x300 resolution
            if img.height > 300 or img.width >300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.user_profile_img.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

django-cropper-image is an app for client side cropping and compressing uploaded images via Django’s app using with help cropper.js. github link [django-cropper-image](https://github.com/aneesh2usman/django_cropper_image).

```
from django.db import models
from django_cropper_image.fields import ImageCropperField
class Images(models.Model):
    image = ImageCropperField(upload_to='image',max_length=255)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pillow to manipulate images in python. You can install it using pip. It has a lot of features which can help you in manipulating images. You can read more about Pillow here:

https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/